# How to integrate using simpsons rule in python without scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to integrate the function g(t)=2e^(-t^2) from 0 to 3 using simpson's rule in python without using the built in simpsons rule in scipy. any help is appreciated

Comment: We already know what you need, now we need to know what your question is, please improve your question and for that read the guide of [ask]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  It would be helpful for you to post what you have tried.  We can help you solve problems, but can't write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can implement simpson's rule without using scipy.  I've given you the skeleton of the code, all you have to do is fill it in correctly.

I'll assume you know what simpson's rule is.  The first thing we have to do is construct a python function for the integrand.

```
import numpy as np

g = lambda t:
```

Next, let's set up a set of evenly spaced points on which we can perform the quadrature.

```
#Sample the function
h = 0.01
a = 0
b = 3
x = np.arange(a,b+h,h)
```

Next, we'll construct an array for the coefficients of simpson's rule.

```
#Coefficients for simpons rule
coefs = np.zeros(x.size)

coefs[0] = #What is the first coefficient or simpson's rule

coefs[1::2] =  #What should the coefficient of the odd xs be
coefs[2::2] =  #What should the coefficient of the even xs be

coefs[-1] = #What is the last coefficient of simpson's rule
```

Simpson's rule is just a sum, which can be computed quite quickly using inner products.

```
#Perform the integration
area = h/3* #Can you express simpson's rule as a dot product?  Look up np.dot or the @ operator

print(area)


#Absolute Error.  Should be O(10^-16) meaning it is very close to scipy's area
from scipy.integrate import simps
print(simps(g(x),x) - area)
```